# remove sprites with animation, different z order

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

How do I remove sprites that are on top of each one but with different z order?

The code that I'm using is:

```
- (void)removeSelectedSprite:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    CCSprite * newSprite = nil;
    for (CCSprite *sprite in selectedSpritesArray) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {            
            newSprite = sprite;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (newSprite) {

        CCSprite *fixedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Animation_01.png"];

        fixedSprite.position = ccp(newSprite.contentSize.width/2,newSprite.contentSize.height/2);
        [newSprite addChild:fixedSprite];

        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {

            [animFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation_%02d.png", i]]];
        }

        CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.05f];
        CCActionInterval *animAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

        id seq = [CCSequence actions: animAction, [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:fixedSprite selector:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanup:)], [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:newSprite selector:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanup:)], nil];
        [fixedSprite runAction:seq];
    }

}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    [self removeSelectedSprite:touchLocation];      
    return TRUE;    
}
```

Why is not working for sprites that are on top of each one (having different z order)?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your implementation of game logic, not a limitation of cocos2d. You can remove any sprite at any time, there is no necessity or benefit for removing sprites in a certain order. If you must remove several sprites at once, simply add them into their own layer or node so that you just need to empty the children array of that layer or node to remove all of them.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I don't want to remove some several sprites at one, only one by one in z-order when my sprites are placed on top of each other; the other case will be lets say tag order.
Sorry for didn't mention correctly what trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if there is a better way but what's coming up in mind is just check the layer childrens and their  z-order and remove based on z-order.

Comment: I came up with [Ray's example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d) but still having problems, not all the objects are removed from my selected objects NSMutableArray; maybe you might now...